# Get item in ListView when associated ImageButton is Clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` in my child xml layout like this:

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/favoriteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/citrus_orange"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
    android:background="@null"
    andorid:onClick="flipVote"/>
```

I programmatically make this button non-focusable in my adapter:

```
ImageButton favButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteButton);

favButton.setFocusable(false);
```

In the same layout, I have a `TextView` like:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/store_id"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="gone" />
```

The click will call the `flipVote(View view)` method:

```
public void flipVote(View view) {
        // make a network call with the value from store_id
     }
```

How do I get the value from the `TextView` associated with the clicked button to include with the network call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the proper way to achieve this is by using Tags. I did it like so:

Adapter

```
// store is data model
favButton.setTag(store.getId());
```

Activity

```
// use it in the flipVote(View view) method
public void flipVote(View view) {
        JSONObject storeVoteData = new JSONObject();

try {
    storeVoteData.put("store_id", view.getTag());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

  // make Volley call with JSONObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter, you have to intercept the click on the button and in the listener make TextView.getText and then call your method flipVote with the value.

Comment: I don't have a listener, the click calls the `flipVote` method automatically.

Comment: You don't have a custom adapter?

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants users to have to click the button specifically, not just anywhere on the list item?

Comment: Yes exactly @MaxSpencer. That was the reason I included `favButton.setFocusable(false);`, as it allows both the button and listview item and the button to be clicked independently. I do indeed have a custom adapter.